# Descargar en cliente archivo .xlsx con libreria Fast-excel-writer

Tags: php

estoy intentando exportar excel .xlsx con la libreria fast-excel-writer ya que los reportes contienen demasiada info. Y spreadsheet es lento para descargarlo. El tema es que, con esta libreria, no lo descarga, sino que lo guarda en el mismo server, no se si alguien mas uso o sabe como realizarlo.
Codigo:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use \avadim\FastExcelWriter\Excel;

$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT .......)

$i = 0;

while ($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {

$data[$i] = array(
    
    $rows['LASTNAME'],
    $rows['FIRSTNAME'],
    $rows['MIDNAME'],
    $rows['READERDESC'],
    $rows['EVENT_TIME_UTC']->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
    $rows['READERDESC_OUT'],
    $rows['EVENTS_OUT_TIME']->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
    $rows['CARDNUM'],
    $rows['SSNO'],
    $rows['FLDCONTRATO'],
    $rows['HORAS_TRABAJADAS']
);
$i++;
}

 $excel = Excel::create(['Sheet1']);
 $sheet = $excel->getSheet();

 $sheet->writeRow(['APELLIDO', 'NOMBRE', 'SEGUNDO NOMBRE', 'LECTORA ENTRADA', 'HORA ENTRADA', 
 'LECTORA SALIDA', 'HORA SALIDA', 'N TARJETA', 'LEGAJO / DNI', 'N CONTRATO', 'HORAS 
  TRABAJADAS']);

 foreach($data as $rowData) {
  $rowOptions = [
    'witdh' => 60,
 ];
$sheet->writeRow($rowData, $rowOptions);
 }

 $excel->save('simple.xlsx');
 ob_clean();
 exit();
```

Leí en GitHub que en la siguiente parte, se pone Download

```
$excel->save('simple.xlsx');
```

Pero no funciona, me tira el siguiente error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method avadim\FastExcelWriter\Excel::download()

Busque en el archivo Excel de la libreria y aparece esto:

```
    public function save($fileName, $overWrite = true)
{
    $this->writer->saveToFile($fileName, $overWrite, $this->getMetadata());
}
```

Pero no hay ninguna función con download. Alguna sugerencia? Gracias

**EDIT A UN PROBLEMA**

Este es el error que me sale al querer descargar el archivo, desde una PC que no sea el servidor:

> PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TEST\Reportes_MDZ\Web\vendor_old\avadim\fast-excel-writer\src\FastExcelWriter\Writer.php on line 265

> PHP Warning:  readfile(simple.xlsx): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TEST\Reportes_MDZ\Web\Query_TEST.php on line 61

> PHP Warning:  unlink(simple.xlsx): No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TEST\Reportes_MDZ\Web\Query_TEST.php on line 63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La librería `FastExcelWriter` no proporciona una función `download()` directamente, por lo que no puedes descargar el archivo directamente desde el servidor utilizando esa función y tampoco tiene algo que lo haga.

Para lograr la descarga, tienes dos opciones:

1. Descargar el archivo utilizando un enlace de descarga normal en el navegador.
2. Crear un flujo de descarga utilizando el encabezado HTTP Content-Disposition.

Te dare un ejemplo de la segunda opción que es la que tengo a mano:

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use \avadim\FastExcelWriter\Excel;

$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT .......");

$data = [];
while ($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data[] = array(
        $rows['LASTNAME'],
        $rows['FIRSTNAME'],
        $rows['MIDNAME'],
        $rows['READERDESC'],
        $rows['EVENT_TIME_UTC']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        $rows['READERDESC_OUT'],
        $rows['EVENTS_OUT_TIME']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        $rows['CARDNUM'],
        $rows['SSNO'],
        $rows['FLDCONTRATO'],
        $rows['HORAS_TRABAJADAS']
    );
}

$excel = Excel::create(['Sheet1']);
$sheet = $excel->getSheet();

$sheet->writeRow(['APELLIDO', 'NOMBRE', 'SEGUNDO NOMBRE', 'LECTORA ENTRADA', 'HORA ENTRADA', 'LECTORA SALIDA', 'HORA SALIDA', 'N TARJETA', 'LEGAJO / DNI', 'N CONTRATO', 'HORAS TRABAJADAS']);

foreach ($data as $rowData) {
    $rowOptions = [
        'width' => 60, // Debes corregir 'witdh' a 'width'
    ];
    $sheet->writeRow($rowData, $rowOptions);
}

$fileName = 'simple.xlsx';
$excel->save($fileName);

// Configurar la descarga
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $fileName . "\"");

// Leer el archivo y enviarlo al navegador
readfile($fileName);

// Eliminar el archivo temporal en el servidor (opcional)
unlink($fileName);

exit();
```

Esoy implementando [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) de php el ejemplo #1 Diálogo de descarga.

Comment: Es lo que necesitaba y funciona perfecto! tenia problemas con los archivos TEMP, solucionaste mi gran problema! muchas gracias!

Comment: Sabes que funciona perfecto en el servidor, pero voy a ejecutarlo en otra maquina, y me manda un error que no me muestra, solo dice 500 - Internal server error., y no descarga el archivo en el cliente.

Comment: Eso puede ser muchas cosas, principalmente cuando a tu server le falta algo para que funcione correctamente la libreria, cuano ocurren errores 500 en un servidor es por que esta configurado para ocultar los errores del php por temas de seguridad, eso es bueno si estas en produccion o mostrando tu web en internet ... cuando ocurre el error 500 entonces tienes que verificar si en el log de errores de apache o php se registro el error, eso es otro tipo de problema, cuando lo encuentres si no sabes como solucionarlo puedes publicar aqui tu consulta con el error especifico y el codigo relacionado.

Comment: Te muestro el error que me sale, al querer descargar el archivo, en un equipo que no sea el servidor. Edito la pregunta, te agradezco desde ya si podes ayudarme!

Comment: @MatiasTonnera el error que reportas no es lo mismo que la pregunta original, te sugiero llevar esa pregunta a otra publicación, no edites ni cambies esta qué ya tenia solución previa.... por otro lado parece que el problema está relacionado a permisos es escritura y lectura...